# Chat Comment Flag window needs to be wider

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

[image]

The text box runs outside of the current popup window.  I think based on other windows like this that the window is to small that or the textbox is too big.

Answer (score 3):

I have pushed a fix for this to our dev server. The change will be live after our next production build.